# Maintain consistency of cursor position when input field is focused onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, sapui5

I have an issue on SAP UI5 application running on Safari Browser.

I have a requirement that `onClick` or tap on any input field, the content in the fields have to get focus or highlight as shown in screenclipping 1.

Unfortunately it only works sometimes. If I use tap on iPad it is not working. Do I have to add any new events or prevent any default behavior?

I tried this way:

```
this.$().click(function() {
  var uAgent = navigator.userAgent ;    
  var input = this.$().find('INPUT');    
  if( uAgent.match(/iPhone/) || uAgent.match(/iPad/) ) {    
    input.get(0).setSelectionRange(0,9999)
  }
  else 
  {
    input.select();    
  }
  this.fireClick({});
}.bind(this));

this.$().mouseup(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
}.bind(this));
}
```

The issue is that the above solution works only sometimes and other times the cursor is at the end. However I would like to focus or highlight on click and make the behavior consistent in both Safari and Chrome. Could you please help on how to prevent the behavior shown in screenclipping2?

Screen clipping 1 behavior on chrome :

Screen Clipping 2 on iPad:
The below code also I tried and is working only few times.Could you please correct the below code if something I have missed out.

```js
sap.m.Input.extend('com.Warehousemgt.controllers.GoodsIssueDetail.ClickableInput', {
   metadata: {
     events : {
       click: {}
           }
   },
   renderer: {},
   onAfterRendering: function() {
    if (sap.m.Input.prototype.onAfterRendering) {
        sap.m.Input.prototype.onAfterRendering.apply(this, arguments);
      }
       $('input').on('focus click touchstart touchend',function(e) { 
     var ua   = navigator.userAgent ;
   if( ua.match(/iPhone/) || ua.match(/iPad/) ) {         

               $(this).get(0).setSelectionRange(0,9999);
      }else 
            {  
                  $(this).select();
                   } 
   });
      $('input').on('mouseup',function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
         });
       }
  });
```

Comment: The images are gonne :S

Comment: I am new to stack overflow so it is not allowing me to add images :(

Comment: I have reworded the title and content a bit to better explain your situation. However, without the images it is not really clear on what you need. I think you may have accidentally removed lines like `[1]: http://test.com/test.img` from the end which are actually the links to your images. You can include the link to your images within the question (or comments) and one of the users who have enough rep will edit it in.

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/PlAy4.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YSLCl.png